# name 'BlogIndexPage' is not defined

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django

Скрин с ошибкой
[image: Скрин с ошибкой]

Скрин с models.py
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин views.py
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выложите еще скрин, views.py.

Comment: Добавил скрин   views.py

Comment: 1. Если вы получаете доступ через админку, проверьте зарегистрирована ли модель в admin.py Пример:`from django.contrib import admin
from .models import * class BlogIndexPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = [''intro",]
    class Meta:
        model = BlogIndexPage`

Comment: Ошибка https://imgur.com/a/d4mP8

Comment: Для более детального разбора проблемы, есть пару вопросов. 1. является ли BlogIndexPage другой моделью? 2. Прикрепите структуру каталогов приложения, полное содержимое model.py, admin.py, views.py, urls.py.

Comment: @VladimirYaremenko admin.py - https://i.imgur.com/KsdYWdZ.png , models.py - https://i.imgur.com/O7AYTQ5.png https://i.imgur.com/vQin8qu.png , views.py - https://i.imgur.com/bAMCy29.png , остальная структура - https://i.imgur.com/WCAkVq5.png

Comment: https://imgur.com/KZpnX9X Основные принципы описал в комментариях, к коду надеюсь поможет в решении проблемы. Если заходить с админки.

Comment: @VladimirYaremenko Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Добавьте свой ответ в вопросу, укажите что именно помогло решить проблему. Чтобы в дальнейшем помочь другим пользователям найти ответ на похожие вопросы.